# How to make Json object in process put into Bigquery Table in Google Dataflow

Tags: java, google-bigquery, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

https://gist.github.com/jeff22222/3ccad995476416809a905a9bf898091a

I am doing the assignment to transform data from CSV on Google Dataflow in Eclipse

some example from my above link

```
            public static class splitProductID extends DoFn<String, String>{
            @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext data){
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JsonObject row = new JsonParser().parse(data.element()).getAsJsonObject();
                    String old_order[]  = row.get("Product_ID").getAsString().split("-");
                    row.addProperty("CategoryID", old_order[0]);
                    row.addProperty("SubCategoryID", old_order[1]);
                    row.addProperty("ProductNumber", old_order[2]);
                    row.remove("Product_ID");
                data.output(gson.toJson(row));`

`PCollection<String> CombinedFiles = pipeline       
                .apply("Read from BQ", BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(TargetTable).usingStandardSql())
                .apply("Tablerow to Json", AsJsons.of(TableRow.class));
            CombinedFiles
                .apply("Split ProductID", ParDo.of(new splitProductID()))
                .apply("Split OrderID", ParDo.of(new splitOrderID()))
                .apply("Split ModePriority", ParDo.of(new splitModePriority()))
                .apply("Calculate Margin and Cost", ParDo.of(new calculateCost()))
                .apply("Writing Result to GCS", TextIO.write().to("gs://fuckfile/Fuck/Result-0004"));
```

now my last process i want to add class that it can put my json object into big query table as my result table but i don't any idea much about how code this one and i am newbie in GCP

Comment: Not my downvote, but the gratuitous profanity might explain it. Could you [edit] to avoid swearing if it's not important for understanding the question?

Answer (score 1):

In your pipeline, you need a `ParDo` transform that generates a `PCollection` to be written to BigQuery and a `BigQueryIO.write*` transform for writing to BigQuery. For the latter, you can either use [BigQueryIO.write()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#write--) with a format function to write arbitrary objects or [BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#writeTableRows--) to write `TableRow` objects.

See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) for documentation on Beam BigQuery sink and [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/BigQueryTornadoes.java) for an example pipeline that reads from and writes to BigQuery.

Comment: I try this similar solution before but it look like it isn't working with my code

Comment: @IntouchsiriSuksawasdipat you should explain what failed for you when you tried that and which error message you got. This is the correct way of writing to BigQuery so it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttobigquery) guide can be useful, where there is already a template source code where you can address to put a json into a BigQuery table.